# Find words in a text file and save them to a new file using Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a program that will find the specific words in txt file, and write the whole line in separate file. For now my program just rewrites the whole file and saves it into the new one. This part is needed for the rest of the program where these lines will be replaced, but that I already created. I'm just a beginner in Java and I can't handle it. Will I need to use regex?

```
import java.io.*;

public class change {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("path\\file.txt"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("path\\newfile.txt"));
            String s;
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null){
                bw.write(s + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            bw.close();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for exact strings there is no need for regex. Sidenote: this task would be far easier in a scripting language Ruby/JS/python

Comment: Basically you just need an `if` statement and the `String.contains` method inside your `while` loop. @Vulwsztyn **far** easier than 10 lines of code? `:D` Since Java 8 you can do this in about 5 lines using `Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))`

Comment: Unless this is purely an academic/leaning exercise, it's crazy overkill to write this in Java **or** Ruby, JS, Python, etc... You can just do: `grep -E "word1|word2|word3" inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues with this code.

### Deplorable exception handling

This code, if a problem occurs, will take all useful information about your exception (which is at least 4 things: The exception's type, the exception's message, the stack trace, and the causual chain), and **tosses it in the garbage**.

You will write bugs. Loads of em. Your assumptions about where your app run will change on you.

Exceptions are **crucial** in managing this.

Stop writing code like this. The fix is easy, and even reduces and simplifies your code! Simply pile `throws Exception` at the end of your `main` declaration (`public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {`) and remove the try, the catch, and the return in the catch.

This way, the exception bubbles up to whatever invokes `main` itself, and that will 'handle' it by printing all the various useful parts and exiting your app. Which is what you want.

### charset violations

Files are bags of bytes, but `Writer` and `Reader` work in terms of characters. Anytime bytes are converted to characters or vice versa, an encoding is applied. UTF-8 is an encoding. So is ISO-8859-1, MacRoman, CP452, etcetera.

If you don't see the encoding being applied then usually that means 'platform default' is applied and you almost never want that. It leads to code that seems to work fine until you run it elsewhere or on different files and then all hell breaks loose.

The fix is to either use APIs which have baked into their specification that they default to UTF_8 (such as the new `Files` API), or to explicitly specify. In passing, unfortunately, `FileWriter` and `FileReader` are not fit for purpose; do not ever use these classes, they are effectively broken as designed. Their API is also obsolete, there's a newer API.

Using the old APIs, you'd fix it as follows:

```
new BufferedWriter(new InputStreamWriter(new FileInputStream("path\\file.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Using the new APIs, well, that's a bit more involved, see below.

### Resource management violation

When you open resources, you must explicitly close them too. Java is a garbage collected language, but the 'point' of garbage collection is that the JVM will run collection when it deems neccessary, and it might be *days* before it does. Thus, any object that takes up more than simply memory if you leave it laying about needs *explicit* closing. "Handles" to files is one such resource: Your OS has a limited supply of these and will flat out refuse to let a process open more files once it has opened a certain amount.  Your code opens files but may not close them anymore: If an exception occurs, that `br.close()` and `bw.close()` line will never be executed.

Java has a tool for this: Automatic Resource Management (ARM), also called 'try-with-resources'. Replace this:

```
BufferedWriter bw = ....;
// do stuff with the writer
bw.close();
```

with:

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = ....) {
    // do stuff with the writer
}
```

The `{}` mark where you use the writer: Java ensures that no matter how you 'exit' out of these `{}`, the resource WILL be closed. Whether you just get to the end of this block, or you return/break/continue out of it, or an exception leads you out of it, the resource is closed.

### Searching for strings

regexps is one way, but if you're looking for a specific exact string that's overkill. Strings have a `.contains()` method.

### New API

There's a new API. The old File API has a nasty tendency to just return `false` when things can't be done instead of telling you about it like 'normal' java APIs. It's also got more flexibility: It can handle such things as managing file ownership, file creation stamps, access control, and links. It also has the nice property that the default charset encoding, if you don't specify anything, is UTF-8 instead of the dreaded and extremely useless 'platform default'.

### Backslashes

Not neccessary, even on windows. `path/file.txt` works just as well. It reads easier and is far more common.

### `var`

You can use `var` instead of writing out the type a second time which can come in handy. `var x = new Foo();` is the same as `Foo x = new Foo()`.

### Putting it all together

```
public class Change {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (
       var bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("path/newfile.txt"));
       var br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("path/file.txt"));
    ) {

      String s;
      while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (s.contains("StringToFind")) {
        // or: s.matches("^.*String[a-zA-Z]WithRegexpToFind.*$")
          bw.write(s + "\n");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you put into writing this. I really appreciate that. I will remember your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I made some code that will find the location of a certain string in a .txt file, which I think is what your looking for.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Help {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // To edit the string your searching for you can get rid input and edit the text variable
    String text = input.nextLine();   
    String line;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testFile.txt"));


    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        if(line.indexOf(text) != -1){
            // enter what you want to do if the string is found here I just put a println statement which you can get rid of
            System.out.println("Found");
        }else{
            // enter what you want to do if the string is not found here I just put a println statement which you can get rid of
           System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }

    br.close();
}
}
```

Links: [How to locate text in string](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-check-if-string-contains-another-substring-in-java-indexof-example.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20contains(),%2C%20it%20will%20return%20%2D1.), [How to read and write files in java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgF21imQ_Is)

Comment: I hope this helps you, let me know if it does, and have a good day